# Mobile Service Client throws exception when response is not found

Tags: c#, azure-mobile-services, windows-10-universal

I am trying to port an application from an azure mobile service to an azure web app.  (the mobile service was working).  I have added microsoft account authentication to the web-app, and the web app api has a MobileAppController attribute.  I have a Universal windows app front end that calls the api.  The app first checks if a player is in the database, if not I get a not found response.  If I call the method using the following code with the MobileServiceClient I get an exception.

```
  private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetAZMAsyncP(string apiext, IDictionary<string,string> param )
    {
       string myuri = String.Format("{0}{1}", urlbase, apiext);
```

//client is the MobileServiceClient that is correctly logged in
    //I do not get response which is 404 not found, I get an exception  "The request could not be completed, Not Found"
            var response = await client.InvokeApiAsync(myuri, System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Get, param);
            return response;
        }
If I call the api from an httpclient and add my own headers, which the mobile client is supposed to do for me, then I get the response as requested. Here is the code:

```
  private async static Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetAZAsync(string apiext)
    {

        string completeUrl = String.Format("{0}{1}", urlbase, apiext);


        // Call out to AZ 
        using (var http = new HttpClient())
        {

         //   http.BaseAddress = new Uri(completeUrl);
         HttpRequestMessage rq = new HttpRequestMessage()
         {
             RequestUri = new Uri(completeUrl),
             Method = HttpMethod.Get
         };
            addauthheader(rq);

            var response = await http.SendAsync(rq);
            return response;
        }
    }
 private static void  addauthheader(HttpRequestMessage rq)
    {
        MobileServiceUser user = App.client.CurrentUser;
       rq.Headers.Add("X-ZUMO-FEATURES", "AT,QS");                    
        rq.Headers.Add("X-ZUMO-INSTALLATION-ID",
            "ff90f37e-0c03-4c52-a343-af711752e383");
        rq.Headers.Add("X-ZUMO-AUTH", user.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken);
       rq.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
        rq.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "ZUMO/2.1");
        rq.Headers.Add("User-Agent",
            "(lang = Managed; os = Windows Store; os_version = --; arch = X86; version = 2.1.40707.0)");
        rq.Headers.Add("X-ZUMO-VERSION",
            "ZUMO/2.1(lang = Managed; os = Windows Store; os_version = --; arch = X86; version = 2.1.40707.0)");
        rq.Headers.Add("ZUMO-API-VERSION", "2.0.0");
               }
```

You can try this out as it is live (and buggy).
https://gamenote2.azurewebsites.net/api/Players?displayname=Paul Goldschmidt&teamid=arizona-diamondbacks
Should give you a 404,
https://gamenote2.azurewebsites.net/api/Players?displayname=Chase Utley&teamid=los-angeles-dodgers
should give you a chase utley object. (YOu will be asked to log into a Microsoft Account).

So my questions: 1.  Can I fix the mobileclient call to get a response instead of an execption
2.  Is there any good reason for me to be spending so much time on this.

Answer (score 1):

If you examine the exception, you will note that the status code is in there - it's just in a property that is not serialized.  Just surround your InvokeApiAsync() call with a try/catch and test for the StatusCode.  It should be a lot easier than writing your own HTTP Client code for the same purpose.

Specifically, `MobileServiceInvalidOperationException` contains the HttpResponse of the failed request, so you can check `exception.Response.StatusCode` value.

Comment: The work around above will be ok, but in principle.  Why should I get an exception when I am asking for an httpresponse?  It appears to me as counter intuitive to get an exception.